# Errors creating generic relations using content types (object_pk)

Tags: mysql, django, django-comments, mysql-error-1170

I am working to use django's ContentType framework to create some generic relations for a my models; after looking at how the django developers do it at `django.contrib.comments.models` I thought I would imitate their approach/conventions:

#### from [django.contrib.comments.models](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments/models.py), line 21):

```
content_type   = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        verbose_name='content type',
        related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s")
object_pk      = models.TextField('object ID')
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
```

That's taken from their source and, of course, their source works for me (I have comments with object_pk's stored just fine (integers, actually); however, I get an error during `syncdb` on table creation that ends:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'object_pk' used in key specification without a key length")
```

Any ideas why they can do it and I can't ?

After looking around, I noticed that [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) actually state:

> Give your model a field that can store a primary-key value from the models you'll be relating to. (For most models, this means an IntegerField or PositiveIntegerField.)
>
> This field must be of the **same type as the primary key of the models that will be involved in the generic relation**. For example, if you use IntegerField, you won't be able to form a generic relation with a model that uses a CharField as a primary key.

But why can they do it and not me ?!

Thanks.

PS: I even tried creating an AbstractBaseModel with these three fields, making it `abstract=True` and using that (in case that had something to do with it) ... same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I typed out that really long question I looked at the mysql and realized that the error was stemming from:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (("content_type", "object_pk"),)
```

Apparently, I can't have it both ways.  Which leaves me torn.  I'll have to open a new question about whether it is better to leave my `object_pk` options open (suppose I use a textfield as a primary key?) or better to enforce the `unique_togetherness`...